# Google cached url for specific site and parmanent url redirection

Tags: asp.net, redirect

first i like know how can i see what are the pages are cached of my web site. say my web site is `www.mysite.com`

i am going to change few urls of my site but there is one problem that i may loose SEO. suppose google cached this page of my url like

`www.mysite.com/detailproduct.aspx?id=200` now i have change the location and name of the page. say now detail product name change to product and url looks like

`www.mysite.com/catalog/products.aspx?id=200` so when people search google  and if this link `www.mysite.com/detailproduct.aspx?id=200` comes in google search and if user click on this link then no relevant page will display. so first of all i need to know what are the different pages has been cached of my web site by google if i know then i can write permanent redirection logic as a result google cache pages url will be change..i guess.

if anyone know any best practice to handle this situation then please discuss in details. the situation is few page name and location has been change and if user search google and if old page url comes then no page will display when user click on those link. i want to handle this situation in best way....what is all of your suggestion. thanks